# 2FA REST API using Postman

Tags: api, rest-api, two-factor-authentication

I have followed the steps at: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/security/two-factor-authentication.html to get a token in order to use Postman to fetch Magento 2 REST endpoints e.g. products, sales etc. But these steps don't give me the expected results.

I have a web api user and a web api customer token configured in the staging environment, but still can't get past 2fa.

Any idea what steps are required to use Magento 2 REST API when 2FA is enabled?

Comment: Thank You! These are the correct steps. I was following the steps in this link: : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/security/two-factor-authentication.html